# Postfix security: Accepting emails for and sending emails from my domains only

Tags: security, postfix, debian-wheezy, smtp-auth

I have a virtual server running Debian Wheezy, and I am trying to configure it as a Postfix mail server. I haven't found though any easy to follow tutorial on how to secure Postfix... and my mail.log file is already full of requests from spammers for sure, since my server is only a few weeks old, and I haven't configured it yet.

So, I am looking for the proper Postfix configuration to accept emails going to my domains or going to other domains only if they are coming from my domains. I don't want Postfix to relay emails from joeblow@NotMyDomain1.com to MrSmith@NotMyDomain2.com.

Also, I would like my SMTP server to require a secure authentication to send emails.

However, let's say I own domains abc.com, def.com and xyz.com, then I want all emails coming from these domains to be relayed by my server if proper authentication is given, and I want all emails going to these domains to be relayed by the server.

And I don't want to restrict emails relaying by network address, since I may be on any network with my laptop, and I want to be able to send emails from it.

I have ssh access to my server, and I have Webmin on it. I don't mind using shell commands, but it would be nice to have a web interface to manage all this and more on my server... if anyone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this mixing hash tables or regex tables containing your domains and tune the parameters `mynetworks`, `relaydomains` and `smtpd_sender_restrictions` permitting only your networks.

Take a look here: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks